# Cubase randomly outputs noise/grain over playing audio

Tags: cubase

After about 10 or so minutes of working in Cubase, I will randomly be playing audio and end up with the audio outputted to my headset to be extremely grainy and noisy. When I stop playing the audio, said grain goes away, but as soon as I play again the grain plays too.

The only way I have found of fixing this problem is by saving my work, closing the software, and opening it again. I have no idea why this is happening.

Initially, I thought it may have been a sound card problem, but after playing audio from different software for longer durations of time and it not having this problem, my theory was proven wrong.

*Computer Specs:*

- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit
- AMD Athlon Dual Core 2.80 GHz 5400B
- 4.00 GB RAM
- Onboard Sound (ASIO)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It does seem a bit localised and not greatly useful for many other people, but there's nothing wrong with it in itself.

Comment: I don't know, I think I have it under control now, though. Re-installed the software and hopefully it will work fine :D

Answer (score 1):

How many audio tracks do you have in your project and how many effects are you using - try reducing the number of effects to see if the problem reduces or goes away. In one of the pull-down menus there is a CPU usage meter - what does this do when the audio breaks up.